# Creating Form UI in SwiftUI

Tags: swift, swiftui, swift5

I am trying to write a basic UI of a form to capture details about a restaurant. I will capture details like:

"NAME", placeHolder: "Fill in the restaurant name",
"TYPE", placeHolder: "Fill in the restaurant type",
"ADDRESS", placeHolder: "Fill in the restaurant address",
"PHONE", placeHolder: "Fill in the restaurant phone",
"DESCRIPTION", placeHolder: "Fill in the restaurant description",

I have designed the basic `TextField` model, stylised it and since I will have to reuse this style across all the entries in the form (as mentioned above) I decided to put the code in a `Struct` in a different SwiftUI file. Till here it is all fine and dandy now since the data is in a different file, I am getting struck at re-using this `Struct` data in `ContentView`. Any help or guidance will help me immensely.

Also, perhaps a silly question but is there any way to create a `TextField` without using a @State variable?

```
import Foundation
import SwiftUI

struct LabelTextField: View {

    @State private var restaurant: String = ""

    var label: String
    var placeHolder: String

    var body: some View {
     VStack(alignment: .leading){
         Text("NAME")
                .font(.headline)
                 TextField("Enter Restaurant Name", text: $restaurant)
                 .padding(.all)
                 .background(Color(red: 239.0/255.0, green: 243.0/255.0, blue: 244.0/255.0, opacity: 1.0))
                 .cornerRadius (5.0)
         } .padding(.horizontal, 15)
 }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are almost there. You just need to pass the required variables to the LabelTextField. And TextField requires a Binding variable. I've updated your code to function as expected. Hope this helps. Happy coding.

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var restaurant: String = ""

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            LabelTextField(label: "NAME", placeHolder: "Fill in the restaurant name", restaurant: $restaurant)
            Text("Restaurant name - \(restaurant)")
        }
    }
}

struct LabelTextField: View {
    var label: String
    var placeHolder: String
    @Binding var restaurant: String

    var body: some View {
        VStack(alignment: .leading) {
            Text(label)
                .font(.headline)
            TextField(placeHolder, text: $restaurant)
                .padding(.all)
                .background(Color(red: 239.0/255.0, green: 243.0/255.0, blue: 244.0/255.0, opacity: 1.0))
                .cornerRadius (5.0)
        }
        .padding(.horizontal, 15)
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you check my code. I meant that it needs a state variable to be passed to it as a binding type.

Comment: I understand. I took those lines form the question posted. Updated the answer.

Comment: Thanks. I checked the code and it worked flawlessly.